# How to make sound play only on current page? Java Script

Tags: javascript, audio

I am a graphic designer building website in Cargo Collective. I want to make sound play when user clicks the mouse or tap the screen. I use this code:

```
<script>
function MouseSound() {
    var fileUrl = "https://files.cargocollective.com/c1242413/sound-1.mp3";
    var audio = new Audio(fileUrl);
    audio.play();
}

window.addEventListener('click', MouseSound , false);
</script>
```

I use function MouseSound() to do it. But I have a problem — the sound keeps playing on the next website page on click, even if there's no script in it. I want to play sound only on pages with the script.

I guess it's because `window` thing? Or it's script just stays in cache? How it's possible to play different sounds on different pages OR just play them only on pages, that have the script? Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to close the tab?

Comment: Just use `document` instead of `window`, this will work for any other website.

Comment: @TechTycho it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes I know, I just posted an answer with more details, but I am just hinting that using `window` generally is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the `window`.

Comment: at least for this case, `document` refers to this tab, `window` refers to the entire window, even if the user is in another tab.

Comment: @TechTycho if it would work like this, you could then run malicious JavaScript on other websites.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `document` instead of `window`. `document` refers to this webpage or DOM. You could do:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", stopSound);
```

This will fire whenever you leave the page, go to a new tab, leave the browser window, close the browser window. You can make a `stopSound()` function that pauses the sound like so:

```js
function stopSound() {
  audio.pause();
}
```

You can also mute the sound with `audio.muted = true`, but this will not pause the sound and sound will play in the background but we cannot hear it.

Now resume the sound with `audio.play()`. you can do:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseenter", playSound);

function playSound() {
  audio.play();
}
```

Just play with the code and see what suites your need.

Comment: Thank you for help and examples! I appreciate it a lot! Will try this.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :( 

This is quick example:
https://cool-vanya.com/test-a
https://cool-vanya.com/test-b

A and B have different sounds. 
When I come to A page, it plays A sound. 
Then I go to B page, it plays A sound + B sound.
And if I go to A page again, it plays A sound + B sound + A sound.

When I reload the page it starts over. My goal is to play A sound on A page, and B sound on B page.

Comment: Can you show me your code, your code is very hard to debug in the devtools. Give me the code for test a and test b.